# Could somebody please tell me what math field this is from?

Tags: calculus

A bit of a stupid question here but I've got 2 more weeks left until a very important exam and probably the only thing I find varying information about online is this: [Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdOgw.png)

Those are only ever used in problems with parametric curves (in the few practice exams I have on me). What exactly are they from?

I found a few different things online of course but there seems to be at least a few different fields where velocity and acceleration are used(kinematics, classical mechanics, etc). What am I supposed to search for?

Comment: Vector calculus.

Comment: Those are pretty elementary. You would encounter them in beginning physics and in a course at the "multivariable/calculus 3" level on curves and surfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, you would see this in vector calculus, classical mechanics (physics), or calculus 3. Further, you might even some of this in an applied linear algebra course.

Comment: Yeah those three seems to be it. Thanks!